# values are empty in session in jsp/servlet

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I am trying to set session values as follows :

```
if (request.getParameter("page") != null) {
                        page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page").toString());
                    }
                    if (request.getParameter("se_tempcardnumber") != null) {
                        tempcardnumber = request.getParameter("se_tempcardnumber").toString();
                        session.setAttribute("session_tempcardnumber", tempcardnumber);
                    }
                    if (request.getParameter("se_empid") != null) {
                        empid = request.getParameter("se_empid").toString();
                        session.setAttribute("session_empid", empid);
                    }
                    if (request.getParameter("se_issuedate") != null) {
                        issuedate = request.getParameter("se_issuedate").toString();
                        session.setAttribute("session_issuedate",issuedate);
                    }
                    if (request.getParameter("se_cardstatus") != null) {
                        cardstatus = request.getParameter("se_cardstatus").toString();
                        session.setAttribute("session_cardstatus", cardstatus);
                    }
```

and i try to access the session values as follows :

```
 if(session.getAttribute("session_empid")!=null) {
                     session_empid =(String)session.getAttribute("session_empid");
                    }
                 if(session.getAttribute("session_tempcardnumber")!=null) {
                     session_tempcardnumber =(String)session.getAttribute("session_tempcardnumber");
                    }
                 if(session.getAttribute("session_issuedate")!=null) {
                     session_issuedate =(String)session.getAttribute("session_issuedate");
                 }
                 if(session.getAttribute("session_cardstatus")!=null) {
                     session_cardstatus =(String)session.getAttribute("session_cardstatus");
                     System.out.println("session_cardstatus : "+session_cardstatus);
                 }
```

for testing purpose i set values for `System.out.println("session_cardstatus : "+session_cardstatus);` alone and i printed the same  thing.

it is getting printed for the first time but when it comes to second time the value is empty though i don't remove anywhere those set variables in session.

Please advise me how to go about;

thanks and regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the session id which is generated before setting values in to session

request.getRequestedSessionId() or session.getId()